# Expressions for $\sin(\arctan(x))$ and $\cos(\arctan(x))$ that do not contain trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Find expressions for $\sin(\arctan(x))$ and $\cos(\arctan(x))$ that do not contain trigonometric functions.

I have been trying to solve it for days, but I just can't figure it out!

Some help would be so nice!

Comment: Hint:  draw a right triangle with legs $1,x$.

Comment: $\tan(\arctan(x))=\frac{\sin(\arctan x)} {\cos(\arctan x)}  =x$ and $\sin^2\arctan x+\cos^2\arctan x=1$

Comment: @Juan Draw a Pythagorean triangle with  x opposit to $ \alpha=$ arctan $x$ and $1$ adjacent side, hypotenuse being $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ Can you now take it from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following triangle:

[image]

Now: $$\tan\theta=\frac x1=x\implies \arctan x=\theta\\\sin\arctan x=\sin\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\\cos\arctan x=\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the right triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,x)$. Then, if $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the hypotenuse, you have:
$$\tan \theta = x$$
So that:
$$\arctan(x)=\theta$$
Now, you have:
$$\sin(\arctan(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
and
$$ \cos(\arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$